# Swift Call async function on main actor from synchronous context

Tags: swift, async-await

I am trying to understand as to why following piece of code throws an assertion. What I am trying to do is to call `asyncFunc()` on main thread/main actor from call site. I don't want to decorate asyncFunc with `@MainActor` as I want the function to be thread agnostic.

```
func asyncFunc() async -> String? {
     dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
     return "abc"
}

func callSite() {
     Task { @MainActor in
          await asyncFunc()
     }
}
```

My understanding was that `Task { @MainActor ...}` would execute all the following code on MainActor/main thread.

Comment: Well, the closure and any synchronous calls in the closure are on the main thread, but not necessarily the inner async functions.

Answer (score 3):

Currently actors in swift are reentrant as mentioned in proposal:

> Actor-isolated functions are reentrant. When an actor-isolated function suspends, reentrancy allows other work to execute on the actor before the original actor-isolated function resumes, which we refer to as interleaving. Reentrancy eliminates a source of deadlocks, where two actors depend on each other, can improve overall performance by not unnecessarily blocking work on actors, and offers opportunities for better scheduling of (e.g.) higher-priority tasks.

Hence, your `asyncFunc` is not run on `MainActor` as it will block the actor from processing other high-priority tasks. To fix this you can try following two approaches:

1. Make your function synchronous, so that it will run on `MainActor`:

```swift
func syncFunc() -> String? {
     dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
     return "abc"
}

func callSite() {
     Task { @MainActor in
         syncFunc()
     }
}
```

2. Or explicitly mark your asynchronous function to be run on `MainActor`:

```swift
@MainActor
func asyncFunc() async -> String? {
     dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
     return "abc"
}

func callSite() {
     Task {
          await asyncFunc()
     }
}
```

Note that same reentrancy rule applies here as well, synchronous calls in `asyncFunc` (i.e. `dispatchPrecondition`) will be executed on `MainActor` while any asynchronous call inside `asyncFunc` will not be called on `MainActor`.